# QGIS Upslope/Downstream Areas

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrography

I am trying to locate areas upstream and downstream of a point of interest in QGIS in order to determine possible areas of origin upstream and areas of impact downstream.  I have used a DEM to create watersheds and am now using the SAGA Upslope Area tool.  I have populated the X and Y fields with the coordinates of a dummy point and used the filled DEM for the Elevation field.  When I run the algorithm, however, the result is always the entirety of whatever I selected for the Target Area field.